# DatatypeMismatch: ERROR just on Postgres but works in SQLite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm getting this frustrating error. Please help! It works fine in SQLite, but throws this error in Postgres

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in JobSeekersController#export_single_record_csv PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer LINE 1: SELECT "phones".* FROM "phones" WHERE (11) ORDER BY "phone... ^ : SELECT "phones".* FROM "phones" WHERE (11) ORDER BY "phones"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

here is my code in job_seekers controller

```
def export_single_record_csv
email = Email.where("email_address = ?", session[:email_jobseeker])      
  @job_seeker = JobSeeker.where("id = ?", email[0].job_seeker_id)

  respond_to do |f|        
    f.csv { send_data @job_seeker.to_csv, filename: "job_seekers-#{Date.today}.csv" }
  end
end
```

here is my code in JobSeeker.rb

```
 def self.to_csv
 CSV.generate(:converters => :all) do |csv|

  all.each do |job_seeker|

    data = Array.new
   phone = Phone.where("job_seeker_id = ?", job_seeker.id).first
    if !phone.mobile_number.blank?
      data.push(phone.mobile_number)
    else
      data.push('null')
    end
```

Comment: The error message is from `export_single_record_csv ` action. Is that the one you've posted?

Comment: Have exactly the same code in export single record as in export csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have some sort Data Type mismatch in either your argument or your database schema. I would log in to your db and describe the job_seekers table to see what all the columns are and their type, make sure there wasn't a mistake made while migrating.

I would also double check what email[0].job_seeker_id has in it as well as session[:email_jobseeker].

Can you run these queries in your console while fetching data from Postgres?
What happens when you put `JobSeeker.where("id = ?", 1)` in console?

Comment: i just restarted the droplet and the same code is working now. Thanks for your help